# It it possible to use delete by query plugin within bulk api in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using **Elasticsearch 2.4**. I want to perform large number of deletion operations together.Each deletion operation has a distinct criteria to delete. [Bulk Delete Query Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html) provides deletion based on query. But, I want to generate `multiple deletion queries` and used it with the [Bulk Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-bulk.html) so that there will be a single request. Is it possible ?

Comment: If delete on query is based on a query, why you can't just concatenate all your delete queries, creating a large query and attach it in the body of delete_by_query?

Comment: delete_By_query use bulk api as written in the documentation that you have posted

Comment: Yes, a larger query could be created. I thought about that. But, I thought  that would be very slow. But, as you said, it uses bulk internally but I am still not sure about the performance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Elasticsearch explicitly mentioned in Bulk API documentation: `The possible actions are index, create, delete and update.`

Please refer to here: [ES 2.x bulk operation guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-bulk.html)

1 step further to version 5.x which I am currently working on, `UpdateByQuery` became built in function but still not included in Bulk operation actions.